# Wireshark isn't displaying the decrypt button on the wireless toolbar

Tags: wireshark

I'm using Wireshark 3.2.2 on linux 5.4 and I'm trying to follow the tutorials and they all seem to get to a step where I press the decrypt button on the wireless toolbar, except my wireless toolbar doesn't have a decrypt button [this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tSve.png) and I would like very much to have a decrypt button.

More than likely I have just misread or misunderstood some key element of working the software, does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: Why not use Wireshark's [802.11 decryption doc](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11) here instead?
Essentially, the toolbar button is a shortcut to changes you can make in preferences.

Comment: Right, I can add the keys, but I cannot perform the second step outlined in the decryption doc, where I click the decryption keys button, and access the decryption key management dialog and select Wireshark and decrypt.

Comment: You don’t need to. Adding the keys and enabling decryption in prefs will make Wireshark load the capture with decrypted layers.

Comment: Then I'm doing something else wrong... Dernit.  Thank you.